# array of strings to go struct

Tags: arrays, json, go

This is the command that i execute

```
$ ps -e
  PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
 4372       1    4372       4372  ?         197608 03:44:57 /usr/bin/mintty
 6476    4372    6476       6208  pty0      197608 03:44:58 /usr/bin/bash
14484    6476   14484      12888  pty0      197608 13:23:48 /usr/bin/ps
```

I get 1d array of strings using `bufio` scanner.scanLines. I need to convert this into array of structs:

```
type ProcessInfo struct {
    PID string `json:"PID"`
    PPID string `json:"PPID"`
    PGID string `json:"PGID"`
    WINPID string    `json:"WINPID"`
    TTY   string `json:"TTY"`
    UID string `json:"UID"`
    STIME string `json:"STIME"`
    COMMAND string `json:"COMMAND"`
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "convert this into array of structs"? Because struct you provided can hold only one line of output.

Comment: @divan Yeah you are right.I meant array of ProcessInfo structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a handy [strings.Fields](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields) function in [strings](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) package that helps to parse this kind of output. Go likes pragmatic approaches, so the naive implementation would be:

- iterate over your array and split each line into fields with whitespace as separator
- construct new ProcessInfo object from these fields
- add this object to the array

Assuming your array is named `lines`, just do something like this:

```
var pinfos []ProcessInfo
for _, line := range lines {
    fields := strings.Fields(line)

    pi := ProcessInfo{
        PID:     fields[0],
        PPID:    fields[1],
        PGID:    fields[2],
        WINPID:  fields[3],
        TTY:     fields[4],
        UID:     fields[5],
        STIME:   fields[6],
        COMMAND: fields[7],
    }

    pinfos = append(pinfos, pi)
}
```

See the whole code here:
https://play.golang.org/p/wo8FFiYabA

Comment: The following code will suffice for any command we execute like "ps" , "ps -e" or "ps -f"                                                                                                             https://play.golang.org/p/G8tDIoZkf9